# JavaScript - How to send multiple XMLHttp requests or force the XMLHTTP request to wait till I get the desired response?

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

I am making a GET request to the api using XMLHttpRequests. The api takes in a "uuid" value denoted by the variable "a" here as a parameter, uses that value for processing and is supposed to spit out some information that I am trying to print to the console.

However, the problem I am running into is that, whenever the api successfully receives the `uuid` value it returns a message where the `newresponse.response.status` is `Initiated`. However I want to wait till the `newresponse.response.status` is `Success` (this usually takes a short bit like 3-4 seconds more).

The original code is shown below:

```
function getrequestresults(status, response) {
  let parse = JSON.parse(response);
  let a = parse.uuid;
  let newrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  newrequest.open('GET', "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/dags/results" + "?" + "uuid" + "=" + a, true);
  newrequest.onload = function() {
    //console.log(newrequest.status);
    console.log(newrequest.response);
  };
  newrequest.send();
}
```

One of the attempts I made at fixing this was as follows:

```
function getrequestresults(status, response) {
  let parse = JSON.parse(response);
  let a = parse.uuid;
  let newrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  newrequest.open('GET', "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/dags/results" + "?" + "uuid" + "=" + a, true);
  newrequest.onload = function() {
    while (newrequest.response.status != "Success") {
      //the following line was just to see what's going on, idea was to keep looping till, desired status is reached
      console.log(newrequest.response);
    }
    //console.log(newrequest.status);
    console.log(newrequest.response);
  };
  newrequest.send();
}
```

However, this did not work as it seems that the "onload" function only runs once, whereas I need it to run multiple times until `newrequest.response.status` is `Success`.

I am quite new with sending XMLHttpRequests and some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `onload` function should check the response. If it's not what you're waiting for, it should call `getrequestresults()` again. Otherwise it should do what you want to do with the response.

Comment: I thought the `onload` function waits till the `newrequest.status` is `200`. Basically the issue is that `newrequest.status` becomes `200` even when `newrequest.response.status` is `Initiated`, this is because I get a resulting msg / data at this stage. Based on my understanding, I think for me to get the desired behaviour I will need to make multiple calls to the api even if `status` is 200 until I get `newrequest.response.status == "Success`.

Comment: The HTTP response code is in `newrequest.status`, not `newrequest.response.status`.

Comment: I think you're confusing `onload` with `onreadystatechange`. `onload` doesn't fire until the response has been received, `onreadystatechange` fires at all the state changes of the XHR.

Comment: But that's the issue, the moment the response has been received is not when the data/DAG has been processed, it is slightly before it.

Comment: Basically even after the the response has been recieved, if I continue to send more `GET` requests with the same `uuid` I will get the data I need

Comment: The issue is I can't say how long the api takes so process the data so I can't know how many `GET` requests to send till the api has completely processed the data (uniquely identified by the `uuid`), the `Initiated` msg I receive when the message is received is secondary. I somehow need to check for `newrequest.response.status == "Success"` and keeping sending `GET` requests till then.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, so you can't wait for an asynchronous function. You can write code that seems to be doing it by using promises and `async/await`.